# OracleBulkCopy is missing in Oracle.DataAccess

Tags: oracle

I want to use OracleBulkCopy to perform some bulk insert operations. My database is Oracle10g and my code is in .NET 2 framework. It is for some old clients and i cannot upgrade database or framework version. 
Is it possible to use OracleBulkCopy for that?
I tried downloading the latest odp.net. I extracted and the latest version was Oracle.DataAccess 2.112.3.0. But I was not able to find OracleBulkCopy in this. 
Please help.

The problem seems something else. I added Oracle.DataAccess to a new project and i can see OracleBulkCopy. For some reason the reference in Visual studio is not refreshing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my dependencies folder, I had multiple versions of Oracle.DataAccess under different folders. Even though I was browsing the path to the latest version, it was not getting updated. It still referrred to assembly from older version path.

Only after i deleted the older version assemblies from other folders, the reference got updated to latest one. But still not sure why was this happening. Anyway it works now.